# How to parallelize the training of an SVC with RBF kernel through MapReduce in scikit-learn for Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, svm

How would I go about splitting up the training of a SVC classifier from the scikit-learn library among multiple processes (or completely separate computers)?  I've found several papers that mention the feasibility of training an SVM iteratively in parallel, but I haven't found any specific examples that apply to the scikit-learn library.

Comment: Training *multiple* classifiers and crossvalidation are both readily parallelized using regular Python modules unrelated to scikit-learn, but it sounds like these papers mention training a *single* classifier using multicore/multinode?

Comment: There's also this: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1433 which links to a libsvm FAQ about using OpenMP. That would exploit multicore, but not multinode.

Comment: That's right.  There are a number of techniques.  The one that has caught my attention uses a Map-Reduce pattern to split the training data between multiple machines, each of which will produce a set of support vectors based on their chunk of data.  The resulting vectors are then added into the base data, and the data is divided up again, and passed back to the nodes.  As the process is repeated, the results from each node are supposed to converge toward a global optimum.  What I'm not clear on is how to get the support vectors out of a trained SVC.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about that technique. But the scikit-learn [SVC docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC) tell me that an object of `SVC` class has an attribute `support_vectors_` that contains the support vectors. Does that help?

Comment: Also, and maybe I'm wrong about this, it's not really ideal to call that task a map-reduce, in the Hadoop sense—I think it was called that because map-reduce was hot a few years ago. It's just an iterative distributed algorithm :)

Comment: ah, that attribute may be exactly the key I was looking for.  As to whether it's a proper map-reduce technique or not, I'll have to take your word for that, as I'm still not familiar with map-reduce. :)